# PHP Command Line in windows not parsing/only output the .php file text

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run a .php script from a powershellscript which I'm having problems getting to work. I started out by troubleshooting in the following way.

Created an `test.php` with the following

```
<?php
 echo "Hello, world!";
?>
```

and in commandprompt I enter `C:\TEMP\xampp\php>php.exe -f C:\TEMP\mailoutput\test.php`

and the output I get in the commandprompt is

```
C:\TEMP\xampp\php>php.exe -f C:\TEMP\mailoutput\test.php
< ? php
 e c h o   " H e l l o ,  w o r l d ! " ;
? >
C:\TEMP\xampp\php>
```

Any clue as to why php.exe isn't parsing the .php file and running the phpcode?

Edit:
Thanks to @Abdulla Nilam in comments i found the answer. The file was encoded with `UCS-2 LE BOM` for some reason. When changing encoding to `ANSI` the file works.

Comment: Thanks, i somehow was unable to find that post even though i searched for an hour.

Comment: *"The file was encoded with UCS-2 LE BOM for some reason."* -- the most probable reason is that it was edited and saved using Notepad. And the solution is to open it again in Notepad, use "Save as" and select `UTF-8` as encoding.

Comment: @axiac Might be the case. I think i used only Notepad++, but i often switch betwen that and notepad so might've missed that.

Comment: Notepad++ is good as well. It is more transparent about the file encoding. Open the file, change the encoding to `UTF-8`, save the file. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Abdulla Nilam in comments i found the answer. The file was encoded with UCS-2 LE BOM for some reason. When changing encoding to ANSI the file works.